# PHP: Algoritmo Descuento Saldos

Tags: php

Resulta que estoy iniciándome en este mundo de programación y en un curso de PHP que estoy realizando, me solicitan hacer un algoritmo para descontar Saldos, este debe :

- Descontar saldo al primer ID que tenga saldo disponible
- Si el utilizado supera lo disponible debe pasar a la siguiente linea.

Tenia todo bien en un principio, pero siempre me descuenta en todos los ID y no logro hacer que se detenga. Me tiene bien frustrado, ya que en el papel es suma y resta. Agradecería enormemente si alguien me pudiese ayudar a "desbloquearme". Muchas gracias!

[image: Tarea]

```html
$a[0]['ID'] = "1";
$a[0]['DISPONIBLE']="15";
$a[0]['UTILIZADO']="15";
$a[1]['ID'] = "2";
$a[1]['DISPONIBLE']="15";
$a[1]['UTILIZADO']="6";
$a[2]['ID'] = "3";
$a[2]['DISPONIBLE']="15";
$a[2]['UTILIZADO']="0";


$b = 7; // SALDO A DESCONTAR

for($c = 0 ; $c < count($a) ; $c++){

    if($a[$c]['DISPONIBLE'] > $a[$c]['UTILIZADO']){

        $a[$c]['UTILIZADO'] += $b;
    }
}
print_r($a);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Metele un break; dentrod de la condicion. Asi se saldra del bucle.

Comment: si mete un break pero tienes que determinar cuando se ejecuta exactamente el break.. si ya recorrió todos los ID...

Comment: Mas vale tarde que nunca, todas las respuestas fueron excelentes y en ese momento me ayudaron a solucionar el tema de saldos de vacaciones. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bastará con indicar un `break` la primera vez que se cumpla la condición.

```
if($a[$c]['DISPONIBLE'] > $a[$c]['UTILIZADO']){
    $a[$c]['UTILIZADO'] += $b;
    break;
}
```

El `break` rompera el ciclo y solo aumentarás el Saldo Utilizado del primer ID con suficiente Saldo Disponible.

Comment: Lo que entiendo es que solo debe de descontar a un ID por todo el ciclo, que cumpla con la segunda condición.

Comment: Por la frase que dice "pasar a la siguiente linea" habia entendido que queria verificar todo. Gracias por la observacion.

Answer (score 0):

```html
$a[0]['ID'] = "1";
$a[0]['DISPONIBLE']="15";
$a[0]['UTILIZADO']="15";
$a[1]['ID'] = "2";
$a[1]['DISPONIBLE']="15";
$a[1]['UTILIZADO']="6";
$a[2]['ID'] = "3";
$a[2]['DISPONIBLE']="15";
$a[2]['UTILIZADO']="0";


$b = 7; // SALDO A DESCONTAR

for($c = 0 ; $c < count($a) ; $c++){

if($a[$c]['DISPONIBLE'] > $a[$c]['UTILIZADO']){

    $disponible = $a[$c]['DISPONIBLE'] - $a[$c]['UTILIZADO'];

    if($disponible <= $b){
     $a[$c]['UTILIZADO'] += $disponible;
     $b -= $disponible;
    }else{
        $a[$c]['UTILIZADO'] += $b;
     $b -= $b;
    }
}
if($b == 0){
   break;
}
}
print_r($a);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: trata de editar tu código que se ve un pequeño error gramatical (Breack; a break;) saludos!